# Equatable implementation doesn't seem working with generics

Tags: ios, generics, swift

I am still fighting with Swift generics. Today I discovered that my implementation of Equatable protocol doesn't work, if it's called from generic class.

My model class:

```
func ==(lhs: Tracking, rhs: Tracking) -> Bool {
    // This method never executes if called from BaseCache
    return lhs.id == rhs.id 
}

class Tracking: NSObject, Equatable, Printable {
    var id: String?
    ..... 
}
```

Class, which uses generic type:

```
class BaseCache<T: NSObject where T: Equatable, T: Printable>  {

    .....

    func removeEntities(entities: [T]) {
        var indexesToRemove = [Int]()
        for i in 0...allEntities.count - 1 {
            let item = allEntities[i]
            for entity in entities {
                println("equal: \(entity == item)")
                // FOR SOME REASONS THE STATEMENT BELOW IS ALWAYS FALSE
                if entity == item {
                    indexesToRemove.append(i)
                    break
                }
            }
        }
        for index in indexesToRemove {
            allEntities.removeAtIndex(index)
        }
        didRemoveEntities()
    }
}
```

and it's subclass:

```
class TrackingCache<T: Tracking>: BaseCache<Tracking> {
}
```

When I call `removeEntities` method of `TrackingCache` instance, I always get `equal: false` in the output, even if `id`s are the same.

But if I move the method to `TrackingCache` class directly, it seems working fine!

Any ideas why this is happening and how to fix this?

Comment: btw, instead of `for i in 0...allEntities.count - 1` you can write `for i in 0..<allEntities.count` – however, assuming `allEntities` is a `CollectionType` you can also write `indices(allEntities)` which is much less error-prone.  That said, you can probably just rewrite the both for loops as `allEntities = allEntities.filter { !contains(entities, $0) }`

Comment: Depending on what `allEntities` is, you may alternatively be able to say `for item in allEntities`.

Comment: He needs an index though, to drive removal later.  `for (idx,item) in enumerate(allEntities)` would work – it relies on `Int` indices, but that's the case here.

Comment: @AirspeedVelocity thanks for suggestion, but it seems `contains` uses `Equatable` implementation, which won't work, right?

Comment: @AndreyGordeev per my answer, it should work if you implement equatable to use `isEqual`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Beware: since `==` is not a member function, it will not give you dynamic dispatch by default, including if you use it alongside a generic placeholder.

Consider the following code:

```
class C: NSObject, Equatable {
    let id: Int
    init(_ id: Int) { self.id = id }
}

// define equality as IDs are equal
func ==(lhs: C, rhs: C) -> Bool {
    return lhs.id == rhs.id 
}

// create two objects with the same ID
let c1 = C(1)
let c2 = C(1)

// true, as expected
c1 == c2
```

OK now create two variables of type `NSObject`, and assign the same values to them:

```
let o1: NSObject = c1
let o2: NSObject = c2

// this will be false
o1 == o2
```

Why?  Because you are invoking the function `func ==(lhs: NSObject, rhs: NSObject) -> Bool`, *not* `func ==(lhs: C, rhs: C) -> Bool`.  Which overloaded function to choose is not determined dynamically at runtime based on what `o1` and `o2` refer to.  It is determined by Swift at compile time, based on the types of `o1` and `o2`, which in this case is `NSObject`.

`NSObject` `==` is implemented differently to your equals – it calls `lhs.isEqual(rhs)`, which falls back if not overridden to checking reference equality (i.e. are the two references pointing at the same object).  They aren’t, so they aren’t equal.

Why does this happen with `BaseCache` but not with `TrackingCache`?  Because `BaseCache` is defined as constraining only to `NSObject`, so `T` only has the capabilities of an `NSObject` – similar to when you assigned `c1` to a variable of type `NSObject`, the `NSObject` version of `==` will be called.

`TrackingCache` on the other hand guarantees `T` will be at least a `Tracking` object, so the version of `==` for tracking is used.  Swift will pick the more "specific" of all possible overloads – `Tracking` is more specific than it's base class, `NSObject`.

Here’s a simpler example, just with generic functions:

```
func f<T: NSObject>(lhs: T, rhs: T) -> Bool {
    return lhs == rhs
}

func g<T: C>(lhs: T, rhs: T) -> Bool {
    return lhs == rhs
}

f(c1, c2) // false
g(c1, c2) // true
```

If you want to fix this, you can override `isEqual`:

```
class C: NSObject, Equatable {
    ...
    override func isEqual(object: AnyObject?) -> Bool {
        return (object as? C)?.id == id
    }
}

// this is now true:
o1 == o2
// as is this:
f(c1, c2)
```

This technique (having `==` call a dynamically-dispatched class method) is also a way to implement this behaviour for your non-NSObject classes.  Structs, of course, don’t have this issue since they don’t support inheritance – score 1 for structs!